# The dimension of a vector space when viewed as real or complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's take a particular example of the space of $m\times n$ matrices with complex entires $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb C)$. My question is can I define this set of matrices on both real and complex vector space?

If the answer is yes, then when $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb C)$ is in a complex vector space then it has a dimension on $mn$. Whereas if it is in a real vector space, its dimension will be $2mn$. Am I right about this dimensionality?

As a second example, a space of $m\times n$ matrices with real entires $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$. This set can only be a real vector space of dimension $mn$, shouldn't it?

Comment: with $M_{m \times n}(\mathbb C)$ as a real vector space  you mean matrix with complex entries but the underlying field in $\mathbb R$? In that case I believe you are correct. Also for the last example, as you would need $\lambda v \in V$ for any element $\lambda$ of the underlying field; if it is $\mathbb C$ and $V = M_{m \times n}(\mathbb R)$ then it's not true that $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ times an element of $V$ is still in $V$, so you can't see it as a vector space over $\mathbb C$. I'm not sure if the dimension can change if you take another field though

Comment: @nougako: The deeper point is, a vector space isn't merely a set, but a set _together with operations of addition and scalar multiplication_ (satisfying a number of axioms). Literally, the set $M_{m \times n}(\mathbf{C})$ isn't a vector space at all until you specify the field of scalars, how to add matrices, and how to multiply them by scalars. (If it matters, the set of complex matrices may also be viewed as an infinite-dimensional _rational_ vector space, by using ordinary addition and ordinary scalar multiplication by rational numbers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first example: yes, because each of the $m \times n$ complex coefficients of your matrix will have 2 coordinates in the base $(1,i)$ of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{C}$.

The base is formed by the matrices $E_{1,1}, iE_{1,1}, ..., E_{m,n},iE_{m,n}$ where the matrices $E_{i,j}$ are the elementary matrices.

For the second example: yes, because this space can only be seen as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space (not a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space).

Comment: Alright got it!

Comment: I misspelled the indexes on the elementary matrices, I'll correct it right now

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. An $m\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ lives in a vector space of dimension $mn$. An $m\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ can be written
$$ M = U + i V $$
where $U$ and $V$ are real $m\times n$ matrices, so the real dimension is $2mn$. (That is, you need to specify $2mn$ real entries to get $M$ in the second case.)